# jquery datepicker change month and day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

When the from-date is picked I want that there is just the possibility of 3-7 days for the to-date. 
so the datarange should be min 3 days and max 7 days.

that works now with following code:

```html
 $(function() {
      $.datepicker.setDefaults({minDate: 0, changeMonth: true, numberOfMonths: 1});
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
       
            var newToDateStart=new Date(selectedDate);
            newToDateStart.setDate(newToDateStart.getDate()+3)
            var newToDateEnd=new Date(selectedDate);
            newToDateEnd.setDate(newToDateEnd.getDate()+7);
          
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newToDateStart);
          $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', newToDateEnd);
            setTimeout(function() { $('#datepicker1').focus(); }, 0);
      }});
      $('#datepicker1').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            
      }});
```

My Problem is the Format. I want it like dd-mm-yyyy. But when i do this the data range doesnt work properly... when i pick today as start-date then the first possible to-date is somewehre in january..

OK solution that works for me now:

```html
$(function() {
      $.datepicker.setDefaults({minDate: 0, changeMonth: true, numberOfMonths: 1, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });


        var d = selectedDate.substr(0,2); // retrieve the day from the string
        var m = selectedDate.substr(3,2); // retrieve the month from the string
        var y = selectedDate.substr(6,4); // retrive the year from the string
        var newToDateStart=new Date(y,m-1,d); // month is zero-based, so subtract 1
        newToDateStart.setDate(newToDateStart.getDate()+3)

        var newToDateEnd=new Date(y,m-1,d);
        newToDateEnd.setDate(newToDateEnd.getDate()+7);

            $('#datepicker1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newToDateStart);
          $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', newToDateEnd);
            setTimeout(function() { $('#datepicker1').focus(); }, 0);
      }});
      $('#datepicker1').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            
      }});
});
```

Comment: Could you show how you are changing the date format? That might provide a clue as to why it stops working when you do so.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: Can you add the full code, html, css and all?

Comment: @primehalo       $.datepicker.setDefaults({minDate: 0, changeMonth: true, numberOfMonths: 1, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I believe what's happening is that you are passing in your selectedDate date string (formatted as 'dd-mm-yy') into the JavaScript function Date() but the function doesn't know that the first two digits are the day and the second two are the month and the third two are the year. So what you would need to do is break down the selectedDate and reformat it into a date string that Date() recognizes (such as mm/dd/yyyy) or break it into separate numbers and pass those in, like:

```
var d = selectedDate.substr(0,2); // retrieve the day from the string
var m = selectedDate.substr(3,2); // retrieve the month from the string
var y = selectedDate.substr(6,2); // retrive the year from the string
var newToDateStart=new Date(y,m-1,d); // month is zero-based, so subtract 1
```

Note: If the year is something like 15 and you pass that into Date() as-is, Date() might think it's 1915 instead of 2015. So depending on what you need, you may want to convert y to a full year instead of just the last two digits.

Comment: almost perfect, I just took var y = selectedDate.substr(6,4);  that for the year

Answer (score 0):

```
var formatedDate = YourDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```